How to handle Async Appends to CSV File Without Corruption
I have a large number of asyncio tasks that are consuming data via a queue and writing to to separate files. However, some of the files will be written to multiple times via mode a+. I have written some code to simulate some random processing in a similar way to my real world example.
I am using asyncio.Lock() in the following fashion to protect the file from whatever task takes ownership of writing to it, but am still receiving CSV results that are misaligned and/or corrupted. Also, the header seems to be getting written multiple times even though the size of the file shouldn't be 0 after the header is first written.
What am I missing?
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import aiofiles.os
import aiocsv
import uuid
import random
import json
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime, timezone

async def write_csv(item: list,  load_id: str, prefix: str) -> None:

    Path("./test_files").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    file_path = Path("./test_files").joinpath(f"{prefix}_{load_id}.csv")

    # Asynchronously write to our file
    async with aiofiles.open(file_path, mode="a+", newline="") as f:

        print(f"INFO: writing file: {Path(file_path).resolve()}")
        w: aiocsv.AsyncWriter = aiocsv.AsyncWriter(f)
        print(f"file size: {await aiofiles.os.path.getsize(file_path)}")

        # If the file is empty, write the header
        if await aiofiles.os.path.getsize(file_path) == 0:
            print("file was empty! writing header")

            # Write the header
            async with asyncio.Lock():
                await w.writerow([
                    "response",
                    "load_id",
                    "last_updated_timestamp_utc"
                ])

        # do something special for specific file name
        # I am just trying to simulate more random data processing
        if prefix == "file_one":
            # Shuffle the chunks again
            item = random.shuffle(item)

        # Write the data
        for chunk in item:
            async with asyncio.Lock():
                await w.writerow([
                    json.dumps(chunk),
                    load_id,
                    datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                ])

async def main() -> None:

    # Create fake data
    items: list[str] = [["hello", "world"], ["asyncio", "test"]] * 500

    # Possible file prefixes
    prefixes: list[str] = ["file_one", "file_two"]

    tasks: list = []
    load_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    for i in items:
        # Randomly assign which file we will write to
        task = asyncio.create_task(write_csv(i, load_id, random.choice(prefixes)))
        tasks.append(task)

    errors = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    # print(errors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())


I guess that something like this happens: Task A opens a file and places file pointer at the current end of the file. Task B opens same file, sets file pointer at same position. Task A appends data to the file. Task B writes data to the position where the end previously was and overwrites parts or all of data written by Task A.

@MichaelButscher this seems probable... but how should I get around this scenario if locking the file handle isn't working?

You have to ensure that for each file at most one file object is open that represents it. One way can be a cache dictionary which maps file paths to weakrefs of file objects. A function returns or creates file objects for a given path. Before the program ends, all remaining file objects in the cache are closed. Instead of weakrefs you can also use wrapper objects for file objects which have a reference counter which is increased and decreased depending on how many tasks need the wrapper. Actual file object is only closed when the counter reaches zero.

Use logging library. It works perfectly in different streams and correctly locks file while appending new data. You can configure logging formatting in such a way that only your text will be appended in the file.

If you want to serialize access to a resource using an asyncio.Lock instance, then all resource accessing code must try to acquire the same lock instance. But you have in your code:
        ...
        # Write the data
        for chunk in item:
            async with asyncio.Lock():
        ...

Each task consequently is creating repeatedly new lock instances, which are not being shared among the other tasks.
A second problem is you have:
        ...
        if prefix == "file_one":
            # Shuffle the chunks again
            item = random.shuffle(item)
        ...

random.shuffle shuffles a sequence in place and returns None. You should have instead:
        ...
        if prefix == "file_one":
            # Shuffle the chunks again
            random.shuffle(item)
        ...

I would also recommend that if you have an open file f, then the size can be most easily determined with:
size = f.seek(0, 2)  # Seek to the end of file and return the offset

In the following code, each task opens the output CSV once but prior to writing a row it makes sure that it is positioned correctly by seeking to the current end of file. The row is then written and the output csv file flushed before releasing control:
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import aiofiles.os
import aiocsv
import uuid
import random
import json
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime, timezone

async def write_csv(lock: asyncio.Lock, item: list,  load_id: str, prefix: str) -> None:

    Path("./test_files").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    file_path = Path("./test_files").joinpath(f"{prefix}_{load_id}.csv")

    async with aiofiles.open(file_path, mode="a+", newline="") as f:
        print(f"INFO: writing file: {Path(file_path).resolve()}")
        w: aiocsv.AsyncWriter = aiocsv.AsyncWriter(f)

        async with lock:
            # Asynchronously write to our file
                size = await f.seek(0, 2)  # Seek to end
                # If the file is empty, write the header
                if size == 0:
                    print("file was empty! writing header")

                    # Write the header
                    await w.writerow([
                        "response",
                        "load_id",
                        "last_updated_timestamp_utc"
                    ])
                    await f.flush()
            # Release the lock implicitly

        # do something special for specific file name
        # I am just trying to simulate more random data processing
        if prefix == "file_one":
            # Shuffle the chunks again
            random.shuffle(item)

        # Write the data
        for chunk in item:
            async with lock:
                size = await f.seek(0, 2) #  # Seek to end
                print(f"{file_path} file size: {size}")
                await w.writerow([
                    json.dumps(chunk),
                    load_id,
                    datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                ])
                await f.flush()

async def main() -> None:

    # Create fake data
    items: list[str] = [["hello", "world"], ["asyncio", "test"]] * 500

    # Possible file prefixes
    prefixes: list[str] = ["file_one", "file_two"]

    tasks: list = []
    load_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    for i in items:
        # Randomly assign which file we will write to
        task = asyncio.create_task(write_csv(lock, i, load_id, random.choice(prefixes)))
        tasks.append(task)

    errors = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    # print(errors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())


Great catch! Yes I should be sharing ownership of the lock, not creating new ones. I'll test this later and accept when I confirm its working.  Thank you!
